# How to launch a new activity from gridview using recyclerview method

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

I want to launch a new activity from one of the grid items available. How do I do that?

Here's the code

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView countryName;
    public ImageView countryPhoto;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GreaterAcc.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

the next is the recylclerview adapter codes

Comment: Hi.  Could you edit your post to make it clear what you are asking, what you have tried and what issue you are having?

Comment: Casillas,I want to know how to launch an activity from a grid view item,I learnt the tutorials from http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/..I have completed the tutorile ,BT I need help on how to launch an activity from the grid view in that tutorial..